# Checking in bash and csh if a command is builtin

Tags: bash, shell, csh

How can I check in bash and csh if commands are builtin? Is there a method compatible with most shells?

Comment: This should really be two questions. `bash` being compliant with POSIX sh, and `csh` being entirely uncompliant, the shells are entirely different; you might as well ask a question about how to do a thing in Python and Java.

Comment: As someone who pretty much exclusively uses bash and csh on a daily basis, and who found this in their first google search result, I found the scope of the question helpful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try using `which` in csh or `type` in bash. If something is a built-in command, it will say so; otherwise, you get the location of the command in your PATH.

In csh:

```
# which echo
echo: shell built-in command.

# which parted
/sbin/parted
```

In bash:

```
# type echo
echo is a shell builtin

# type parted
parted is /sbin/parted
```

`type` might also show something like this:

```
# type clear
clear is hashed (/usr/bin/clear)
```

...which means that it's not a built-in, but that bash has stored its location in a hashtable to speed up access to it; *(a little bit)* more in [this post on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105876/what-does-rm-is-hashed-mean).

Comment: `type` also seems to work with fish shell.

Answer (score 13):

In bash, you can use the `type` command with the `-t` option. Full details can be found in the `bash-builtins` man page but the relevant bit is:

> **type** -t name
>
> If the `-t` option is used, type prints a string which is one of `alias`, `keyword`, `function`, `builtin`, or `file` if name is an alias, shell reserved word, function, builtin, or disk file, respectively. If the name is not found, then nothing is printed, and an exit status of false is returned.

Hence you can use a check such as:

```
if [[ "$(type -t read)" == "builtin" ]] ; then echo read ; fi
if [[ "$(type -t cd)"   == "builtin" ]] ; then echo cd   ; fi
if [[ "$(type -t ls)"   == "builtin" ]] ; then echo ls   ; fi
```

which would result in the output:

```
read
cd
```

Answer (score 4):

For `bash`, use `type command`

Answer (score 2):

For `csh`, you can use:

`which command-name`

If it's built-in, it will tell so.
Not sure if it works the same for bash.
We careful with aliases, though. There may be options for that.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are close, but they all fail if there is an alias or function with the same name as the command you're checking.

Here's my solution:

### In `tcsh`

Use the `where` command, which gives all occurrences of the command name, including whether it's a built-in.  Then `grep` to see if one of the lines says that it's a built-in.

```
alias isbuiltin 'test \!:1 != "builtin" && where \!:1 | egrep "built-?in" > /dev/null || echo \!:1" is not a built-in"'
```

### In `bash`/`zsh`

Use `type -a`, which gives all occurrences of the command name, including whether it's a built-in.  Then `grep` to see if one of the lines says that it's a built-in.

```
isbuiltin() {
  if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 command"
    return 1
  fi
  cmd=$1
  if ! type -a $cmd 2> /dev/null | egrep '\<built-?in\>' > /dev/null
  then
    printf "$cmd is not a built-in\n" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}
```

### In `ksh88`/`ksh93`

Open a sub-shell so that you can remove any aliases or command names of the same name.  Then in the subshell, use `whence -v`.  There's also some extra archaic syntax in this solution to support `ksh88`.

```
isbuiltin() {
  if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 command"
    return 1
  fi
  cmd=$1
  if (
       #Open a subshell so that aliases and functions can be safely removed,
       #  allowing `whence -v` to see the built-in command if there is one.
       unalias "$cmd";
       if [[ "$cmd" != '.' ]] && typeset -f | egrep "^(function *$cmd|$cmd\(\))" > /dev/null 2>&1
       then
         #Remove the function iff it exists.
         #Since `unset` is a special built-in, the subshell dies if it fails
         unset -f "$cmd";
       fi
       PATH='/no';
       #NOTE: we can't use `whence -a` because it's not supported in older versions of ksh
       whence -v "$cmd" 2>&1
     ) 2> /dev/null | grep -v 'not found' | grep 'builtin' > /dev/null 2>&1
  then
    #No-op
    :
  else
    printf "$cmd is not a built-in\n" >&2
    return 1
  fi
}
```

### Using the Solution

Once you applied the aforementioned solution in the shell of your choice, you can use it like this...

At the command line:

```
$ isbuiltin command
```

If the command is a built-in, it prints nothing; otherwise, it prints a message to stderr.

Or you can use it like this in a script:

```
if isbuiltin $cmd 2> /dev/null
then
  echo "$cmd is a built-in"
else
  echo "$cmd is NOT a built-in"
fi
```